# Best choice to recover a unix device driver by killing a kthread

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I don't see any kthread_destroy for Linux, only for NetBSD.

Which would be the best approach to kill a kthread and then start it again ?

Comment: Reboot the OS.  Your kernel is un an undefined state.  Get rid of it and replace it with a new one.

Answer (score 1):

linux doesn't support killing a kernel thread. You ask it to stop, then wait for it to do so (there's really no provision for buggy kernel modules). That way, it doesn't suddenly disappear leaving system resources -- locks, allocated memory, and so forth -- in an indeterminate state.

Typically you use kthread_create to create the thread, and kthread_stop to ask the thread to stop. Meanwhile the thread sits in a loop doing something like this:

```
while (!kthread_should_stop()) {
   /* ... do stuff */
}
return 0;
```